# How come my Emulator isn't starting within Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

```
> Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:checkDebugAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:extractDeepLinksDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugMainManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugManifestForPackage UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugKotlin UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugNativeDebugMetadata NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compressDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:mergeDebugJavaResource UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:desugarDebugFileDependencies UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeExtDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeLibDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:dexBuilderDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeProjectDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugNativeLibs UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:stripDebugDebugSymbols NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:validateSigningDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:packageDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:assembleDebug UP-TO-DATE
> BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 922ms
> 27 actionable tasks: 27 up-to-date
> Build Analyzer results available
```

That's the message I got in my Build Log as I ran my app and tried opening my Emulator, I just started a new project and it's giving me this issue now randomly as I try to start... It keeps saying "The emulator process for AVD Pixel_2_API_29 was killed"

I updated the Android Studio itself recently, there are no more updates needed so I don't know what the issue could be.

Only thing I can think of is some / most Android files are saved within another drive, I saved this project in my D:/ drive as I had no more space to save within my other.

Comment: Gradle output is completely irrelevant, as it does not show the `emulator` startup.

Comment: What could be the issue  then?

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not a clairvoyant... GL drivers would be my best bet. See the Q&A linked above. There's tons of dupes: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bandroid-emulator%5D+%22was+killed%22 (as an example of how to use the search feature before asking).